# Completable Future inside completable future

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have couple of completable future in my code. Inside one of completable future I want another completable future (completable future inside completable future) e.g.

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> buildEmployee (List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {
    return supplyAsync(() -> {

        Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>> rewards = rewards(employeeInfo);
        Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>> points = points(employeeInfo);
    }, executor);
}
```

In above method rewards and points are two independent sequential call, I want it to parallel call for them for that I tried -

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> buildEmployee (List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {
    return supplyAsync(() -> {

        CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>>> rewards = reward(employeeInfo);
        CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>>> points = points(employeeInfo);

        CompletableFuture<Void> futures = allOf(rewards, points);
    }, executor);
}
```

1. Is is correct way to do this? How can I improve it if not correct way?

I am building `<List<Employee>>` as below

```
employeeInfo.stream.map(employee -> Employee.builder().
  .<someEmplyInfo>
  .points(points.getOrDefault(employee.getEmpId, newArrayList()))
);
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: I updated the question. I mean still is taking long time to return so my question how can improve it or is it a correct way to do this.

Comment: What are the signatures of methods `reward(...)` and `points(...)`?  You are calling them inconsistently. How do you construct `List<Employee>` from the output of those two methods?  In other words, please include a sequential version of this method that compiles and works correctly.

Comment: `reward(...)` and `points(...)` method calls API to get details respectively. Once it get details it collect into List and put it into map against empId.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to handle any exceptions in exceptionally block for individual futures.

Ideally, the flow of control should not be dependent on the exception handling logic, it should be wrapped in a status object that can be used to evaluate if further processing should happen. 
Adding a thenApply post the allOf method and then fetching the results within the thenApply block should do the trick

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> buildEmployee(List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {
    //Build the future instance for reward
    CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>>> rewardsFuture = reward(employeeInfo)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            //Handle the error
            return null;
        });

    //Build the future instance for points
    CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>>> pointsFuture = points(employeeInfo)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            //Handle the error for rewards
            return null;
        });

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(rewardsFuture, pointsFuture).thenApply(v -> {
        try {
            Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>> rewardsResult = rewardsFuture.get();
            Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>> pointsResult = pointsFuture.get();

            //Convert the above map to the desired list of string
            List<Employee> buildEmployeeResult = null;
            return buildEmployeeResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle exception
            return null;
        }
    }, executor);
}

private CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>>> points(List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {
    return supplyAsync(() -> {
        //Logic for points synchronous
    });
}

private CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>>> reward(List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {
    return supplyAsync(() -> {
        //Logic for rewards synchronous
    });
}
```

Comment: Exceptionally block should be used, unless you are confident or have reason not to do so. @Deepak. using .thenApplyAsync would not make any difference as within the method block    buildEmployee(.....) there are no any other operations being executed or expected parallely with .thenApplyAsync(...).
Two .get(...) operation are already futures and would finish within .thenApplyAsync(...).
Use .thenApply(...) instead as .thenApplyAsync(...) would not benefit  as it should and may make developer confuse of the behavior.

Comment: Agreed @Nimeshmakwana

Comment: To avoid using commonPool, pass the `executor ` in the `supplyAsync` of reward and points function also

Answer (score 0):

In the above approach you are using `Async` thread to execute `buildEmployee` method, which means `Async` thread is responsible to make two API calls `rewards` and `points` and then it will combine the result. so in the above approach this method is executing asynchronously but not the API calls.

But you can do it another way by making API calls Asynchronously, do the `reward` call asynchronously by using `supplyAsync` and then do the `points` call using Main thread. Finally block the main thread until async call get finished and then combine the result

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> buildEmployee (List<EmployeeResponse> employeeInfo) {

       // First call is Async call        

    CompletableFuture<Map<String, List<EmployeeReward>>> rewards = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->reward(employeeInfo), executor);

      //Second call by main thread

    Map<String, List<EmployeePoints>>> points = points(employeeInfo);

    // main thread is Blocked and get the result of the future.
      rewards.get(); //throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException

   // Now combine the result and return list

      return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);

}
```

Comment: but `List<Employee> buildEmployee` is another completable future - `CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> employee = employeeInfo.isPresent() ?
            employeeService.buildEmployee(employeeInfo.get()) : completedFuture(null);`